Limit WebSocket Message sizes
My requests are passed through an nginx and then envoy.
However, i could not identify a way to limit the message sizes that can pass through a websocket connections.
checked per_connection_buffer_limit_bytes and did not work
I cannot reduce proxy buffer sizes since it will affect http request payloads..
